# Oracle APEX (21.2) Database Design - Split Numbers vs Normalization

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I know this is overall a database design question, but I think there is validity of listing it with APEX due to the nature of the implementation I am thinking of with use of APEX_STRING.SPLIT_NUMBERS api.

With that out of the way, I have a consent form table that once created will need to be assigned to different 'target' groups (e.g. School Pyramid, School Level [High School, Middle School, Elementary], Grade Level [1-12], or even specific schools [by a School ID]). More than 1 pyramid can be targeted (total of 5), more than 1 school can be targeted (up tp 10) for a given consent form.

My initial thought was a table that has all these target groups (with associated reference/lookup tables REF_PYRAMID, REF_SCHOOL_LEVEL, REF_SCHOOL). Then store the IDs in the associated column as a list of numbers (eg. 2:12:13). Then I would use `APEX_STRING.SPLIT_NUMBERS` & `MEMBER OF` when I need to run SQL check to see if parent is part of an authorized target & should have access to the consent form.

I am not used to storing info this way so wondering if there are any downsides of this approach? This keeps the record flat and allows the option to make a consent form school-wide, which is just Y/N option not multiple targets, like the others.

```sql
dpc_consent_form_target {
  target_id                 number         [primary key]
  consent_form_id           number         [ref: > dpc_consent_form.consent_form_id]
  school_wide               char(1)        [chk 'Y','N']
  pyramid_id                number
  school_id                 number
  school_level_id           number
  grade_id                  number
}
```

My second thought was to normalize the design, like I usually would, so that each, say School, would have it's own record in a TARGET table, but then I'm not sure how best to handle the single "record" of school-wide.

```sql
table dpc_consent_form_target {
  target_id                 number         [primary key]
  consent_form_id           number         [ref: > dpc_consent_form.consent_form_id]
  target_type_id            number         [ref: > dpc_ref_target_type.target_type_id]
  target_value_id           number
  created_by                varchar2(50)
  created_date              timestamp
  updated_by                varchar2(50)
  updated_date              timestamp
}

table dpc_ref_target_type {
  target_type_id            number         [primary key]
  target_type_name          varchar2(50)
  active_flag               char(1)
  created_by                varchar2(50)
  created_date              timestamp
  updated_by                varchar2(50)
  updated_date              timestamp
  deleted_by                varchar2(50)
  deleted_date              timestamp
}

TARGET TYPE VALUES:
1 - pyramid_id
2 - school_level_id
3 - school_id
4 - grade_id
5 - school_wide
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then store the IDs in the associated column as a list of numbers (eg. 2:12:13).

Don't do that.

Apex concatenates `RETURN` values for e.g. Shuttle items and everything works just fine *in Apex world*. However, as soon as you step out of it and have to write queries based on such a data, you'll have to split values into rows so that you could join them to other table(s).

It *works*, can be done, no problem; however, that's not the way to do it because data model isn't normalized. Also, you can't create any meaningful index on it because you'd be indexing a colon-separated string, not each value within; no difference in performance when you have a small data set, but it *will* suffer on large data sets.

What to do? Create a *child* table which will reference its master table via foreign key constraint.

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot, that is what 'feels' more natural to me as well, but wasn't sure if the 1st option was an APEX "approved" solution. I'll stick to the normalized approach. I appreciate your help.